# Extract list of url from a page using importxml

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

is a way to **scrape** all the links from this list using importxml ?
The page is :
http://www.derecho.uba.ar/academica/asuntos_estudiantiles/pasantias/ofertas_anteriores.php

When i use this xpath only returns the name of the links , not the urls

//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "listaLinks", " " ))]//a

It gives me "General Motors de Argentina S.R.L." when i want the url of that link , i need the url of all the different names of that list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "listaLinks", " " ))]//a/@href`